# Internet explorer runs a file .mp4 video incorrectly

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video, codec, windows-media-player

I have a video that was recorded on a cellphone with the format MP4 and on Portrait screen orientation. Then I put it in this tag:

```
<video>
 <source src="http://myserver/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4;">
</video>
```

and I also tried:

```
<video>
  <source src="http://myserver/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4;codecs=avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2">
</video>
```

On Chrome and Firefox, both work perfectly.

**OS**: Windows 7

**The problem**: On Internet Explorer (9,10,11 and Edge), even the orientation of the video being the portrait, I can see it only in the landscape orientation. (With a rotation of 90 degrees)

I've installed **Windows Media Player Classic** and **K-Lite Codec Pack** and after that, I can see the video in the correct orientation only on the **Windows Media Player Classic**.

I mean, until now, I can see the video properly neither on Internet Explorer nor on Windows Media Player.

At first, I thought the problem could be something related to the tag `<video>` that couldn't work properly on Internet Explorer. But now I'm almost sure that the problem is related to some Codec or some updating related to the Windows that it is missing, but I searched a lot and I didn't find anything that could help me.

Comment: Did you rename the video extension? Use the networking tab of the f12 dev tool to inspect the response Mime-type.

Comment: The extension is correct.
**Accept-Ranges:** bytes  
**Connection:** keep-alive  
**Content-Length:** 3730959  
**Content-Range:** bytes 0-3730958/3730959  
**Content-Type:** video/mp4  
**Date:** Tue, 09 Jan 2018 15:42:26 GMT  
**ETag:** "7d23ac538984d31:0"  
**Last-Modified:** Wed, 03 Jan 2018 11:52:27 GMT  
**Server:** Microsoft-IIS/8.5  
**Via:** 1.1 S1334 (squid)  
**X-Cache:** MISS from S1334  
**X-Cache-Lookup:** MISS from S1334:8080